# Return list of possible address matches from google?

Tags: google-maps, geocode

I am trying to add functionality to a web app of mine that allows a user to enter an address estimation, for example "McDonalds, Detroit, MI", and then select the exact address from a list of possible matches.

I am already familiar with direct geocoding (address -> lat, lng) and reverse geocoding (lat, lng -> address).  Does anyone know how I can accomplish the above using just the google geocoding API?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When you geocode the address google returns a list of possible matches in the response

[A geocode request for main st](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=Main+st&sensor=false) returns 2 results in new york, 1 in utah, 1 in maine, etc...

You just parse the response to get the different locations

Answer (score 0):

You can't. Google's Geocoder will not match on business locations in the majority of cases. What you want is a combination of local search + geocoding, or a address suggest service, which Google's Geocoding service doesn't offer.

Answer (score 0):

Galen is right, here's working code against V3 - I found the suggestions in the Placemarks attribute of the results. Try address = "Broad Street" in the below example.

```
if (geocoder) {
                geocoder.getLocations(
                address,
                function (results) {
                    if (!results) {
                        alert(address + " no suggestions");
                    } else {
                        $('#output').html('');
                        if (results.Placemark) {
                            for (var i = 0; i < results.Placemark.length; i++) {
                                $('#output').append(i + ': ' + results.Placemark[i].address + '<br/>');
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
```